# Non-blocking parsing of a JSON String to a JsonNode

Tags: json, jackson, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, nonblocking

I'm exploring reactive programming with Spring Webflux and therefore, I'm trying to make my code completely nonblocking to get all the benefits of a reactive application.

Currently my code for the method to parse a Json String to a JsonNode to get specific values (in this case the elementId) looks like this:

```
public Mono<String> readElementIdFromJsonString(String jsonString){
    final JsonNode jsonNode;
    try {
        jsonNode = MAPPER.readTree(jsonString);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return Mono.error(e);
    }

    final String elementId = jsonNode.get("elementId").asText();

    return Mono.just(elementId);
}
```

However, IntelliJ notifies me that I'm using an inappropriate blocking method call with this code:

```
MAPPER.readTree(jsonString);
```

How can I implement this code in a nonblocking way? I have seen that since Jackson 2.9+, it is possible to parse a Json String in a nonblocking async way, but I don't know how to use that API and I couldn't find an example how to do it correctly.

Comment: Take a look on [async-jackson](https://github.com/mmimica/async-jackson) and [AsyncJsonParser](https://github.com/mmimica/async-jackson/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mmimica/ajackson/AsyncJsonParser.java) class.

Comment: I thought that Jackson supports async non blocking json parsing by default since the release 2.9+ without any additional libraries?

Comment: This is not an additional library - just an example how to use `Jackson` classes. You can try to use that `AsyncJsonParser` or just copy the most important methods from it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why it is saying it is a blocking call since Jackson is non blocking as far as I know. Anyway one way to resolve this issue is to use schedulers if you do not want to use any other library. Like this.

```
public Mono<String> readElementIdFromJsonString(String input)  {

    return Mono.just(Mapper.readTree(input))
               .map(it -> it.get("elementId").asText())
               .onErrorResume( it -> Mono.error(it))
               .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
}
```

Something along that line.

Answer (score -1):

```
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

import org.springframework.core.ResolvableType;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferUtils;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DefaultDataBuffer;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DefaultDataBufferFactory;
import org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder;
import org.springframework.util.MimeType;
import org.springframework.util.MimeTypeUtils;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface MessageParser<T> {

    Mono<T> parse(String message);
}

public class JsonNodeParser extends AbstractJackson2Decoder implements MessageParser<JsonNode> {

    private static final MimeType MIME_TYPE = MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON;
    private static final ObjectMapper OBJECT_MAPPER = allocateDefaultObjectMapper();

    private final DefaultDataBufferFactory factory;
    private final ResolvableType resolvableType;

    public JsonNodeParser(final Environment env) {
        super(OBJECT_MAPPER, MIME_TYPE);

        this.factory = new DefaultDataBufferFactory();
        this.resolvableType = ResolvableType.forClass(JsonNode.class);

        this.setMaxInMemorySize(100000); // 1MB

        canDecodeJsonNode();
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<JsonNode> parse(final String message) {
        final byte[] bytes = message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        return decode(bytes);
    }

    private Mono<JsonNode> decode(final byte[] bytes) {
        final DefaultDataBuffer defaultDataBuffer = this.factory.wrap(bytes);

        return this.decodeToMono(Mono.just(defaultDataBuffer), this.resolvableType, MIME_TYPE, Map.of())
            .ofType(JsonNode.class)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .doFinally((t) -> DataBufferUtils.release(defaultDataBuffer));
    }

    private void canDecodeJsonNode() {
        if (!canDecode(this.resolvableType, MIME_TYPE)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("JsonNodeParser doesn't supports the given tar`enter code here`get " +
                "element type [%s] and the MIME type [%s]", this.resolvableType, MIME_TYPE));
        }
    }
}
```